# How to branch properly for multiple releases with TFS

Tags: tfs, branch

I guess this has been asked multiple times already but couldn't find a quick and complete answer.

Let's say I start from scratch and would like to set up TFS project to work with 2 parallel releases which could evolve differently but still I want to be able to push a bugfix in both, let's call them REL. A and REL. B, both will have code changes not shared among them but could be that a bugfix from REL. A should be pushed into REL. B.

starting from the beginning, do I create the main or the dev first and which one is a branch of the other?

REL. A is a branch of Dev or Main?

REL. B is a branch of REL. A or a branch of Main or Dev?

Thanks.

Comment: Just as a clarification - will the code from Release A and Release B eventually be merged together, or is this more of a situation where Release A will always be a different product from Release B?

Comment: always different products, but we need a common root to use to propagate bug fixes to both in case the bug was in a common part shared by both before the branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.  Based on that, here's my high-level recommendation.

Since these are different products, you can go with a branch-on-product approach.  In this approach, you would have:

> MAIN - The baseline code.
>   BugFix -Branched from main.  (This is where any shared bug fixes would occur)
>   Product A - Branched from main.
>   Product B - Branched from main.

I would then recommend a "Dev" branch branched off of each of the Bugfix, Product A, and Product B branches (just for good SCM practices)

The majority of your work would be done in your product branches.  If a bug needed to be fixed, the ideal thing to do would be to code and test it in your BugFix branch.  Once it has been certified to work with the "root" code, you would merge that fix to MAIN, then forward merge it to Product A and Product B.

In a less ideal situation, if the bug was fixed in Product A and needed to be reflected in Product B, you could cherry-pick merge just that code from Product A to MAIN, then from MAIN to Product B and BugFix.  Keep in mind that this is a dangerous approach, in that you may inadvertently merge features from Product A to Product B.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) , that can be used to choose the branching structure.